# The site in vue.js does not load. What could be wrong?

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I have a frontend of my SPA site that I wrote and tested on my local machine(everything worked). After getting familiar with apache, configuring it and fixing bugs, when I go to the domain, my site does not show up.
In the center of the page I see a
[loading element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B1cU.png),
in place of the favicon I see a [vue icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2VS0.png),
and in developer mode I see an error[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nplPt.png).

error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: component is not defined
at 48 (Footer.vue?5b80:11:19)
at f (bootstrap:84:22)
at 32 (1903dcc.js:1:41005)
at f (bootstrap:84:22)
at Module.<anonymous> (1903dcc.js:1:15960)
at 217 (1903dcc.js:1:27650)
at f (bootstrap:84:22)
at 215 (1903dcc.js:1:15700)
at f (bootstrap:84:22)
at t (bootstrap:45:15)
```

What can it be related to and how can I fix it?

P.S. This is my first question on this service, so if I wrote my question unclear, misspelled it, gave too little information, write about it. Thanks :)

I thought the problem was in my Footer.vue file.

Footer.vue

```
<template>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="float-right">
        <a href="#">Up</a>
      </p>
      <span class="text-muted">Footer.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Footer'
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I checked it for errors and found nothing.
I also found no errors in the files where I use
[Footer.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKNJJ.png)

post_detail.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <Nuxt />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import Navbar from "~/components/Navbar";
import Footer from "~/components/Footer";
export default {
  components: {
    Footer,
    Navbar,
  },
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        { rel: "canonical", href: `http://localhost:3000${this.$route.path}`}
      ]
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

default.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <Slider />
    <div class="container">
     <Nuxt />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import Navbar from "~/components/Navbar.vue";
  import Slider from "~/components/Slider.vue";
  import Footer from "~/components/Footer.vue";
  export default {
    components: {
      Footer,
      Slider,
      Navbar,
    },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

style.css

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #31373e;
}
```

The fourth file is Footer.vue itself.
I also tried googling the error from the console, but didn't find a solution that could help me.

Comment: Is nuxt globally included?

Comment: Do you mean does apache work? If yes, then apache works. If not, please complete your question :)

Comment: Can you transcribe that error as text in the question?

Comment: Done. I have added a description of the error 

Answer (score 0):

You are using nuxt, since v2.13 nuxt version components are auto-import (if "components" option is "true" in the nuxt config.)
In the your code, components manually register using import, i guess problem related this conflicted.

Comment: I checked and tried to specify "components: false" in nuxt.config.js, but it didn't work.

Comment: Only the footer has an error? If yes can you delete footer.vue and add new component with other name like MainFooter.vue?